# How to change line length in Fusion 360sketch?

Tags: autodesk-fusion-360

I have a line that I need to extends from 28 mm to 54mm:

[image]

The red one is the one I want to extends down. How can I do that? I tried all combinations of clicks I could think of, but I cannot find how to edit parameters of the line.

Comment: this is not a graphic design question. But yes you need to remove the point on entity constraint.